# what does Exclamation mark mean?

Tags: flex-lexer, lexer

I am reading some [flex](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~cr4bd/flex-manual/) file for a dialect of datalog, the original file is [ol_lexer.lex](https://github.com/declarativitydotnet/p2/blob/master/lang/parse/olg_lexer.lex) there is a code snippet in the action part:

```
<INITIAL>%%.*           ; // Ignore %% comments
<INITIAL>^#!.*          ; // Ignore '#' directives
```

I know the second line for matching the preprocessing directives such as

```
#define PI 3.14
```

but I don't know what's meaning of the mark "!" here, or why the second pattern needs the exclamation mark ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second line ignores lines that start with `#!` (so it would not match `#define ...` as that doesn't have a `!` after the `#`). The `!` doesn't have any special meaning here - it just matches an exclamation mark.

I assume the purpose of this rule is to allow shebang line (such as `#!/usr/bin/env myinterpreter`).

Comment: Thanks, sepp2k, your answer is right. I also can match "#define xoxo 5" even if I comment the second. But I still have a question which pattern match "#define xoxo 5" in the file [ol_lexer.lex](https://github.com/declarativitydotnet/p2/blob/master/lang/parse/olg_lexer.lex), I did not find the pattern, would you like to help me for that? thanks in advance

Comment: @abelard2008 I don't see anything in there that would match a `#define` - maybe the input is run through a preprocessor first?

Comment: You are great! Your guess was right and reminded me. This does have a preprocessor  in the processing of flex file.